# Will Xampp affect by log4j?

Tags: xampp, log4j

We have installed Xampp in D Drive at windows server 2016 suddenly that Drive changed its format from NTFS to RAW..

System admin suspect that it will affected by log4j due to the usage of apache service so that only Drives are encrypted.. But We were not use any log4j in our server because we use php and mysql..

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick check on this and although log4j is part of the Apache foundation, Apache httpd is not written in Java so it does not include log4j. As far as I'm aware, none of the XAMPP components are written in Java.